# How to get status of assertResponseOk - laravel 4.2 testing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

It may be very basic question but I could not found any answer for it because of being very new to phpunit and laravel.

I have to test an api, first I assert for the response

```
$this->assertResponseOk();
```

Then I am playing with response, and asserting for equality

```
$response = $response->getOriginalContent();
$response = json_decode($response);
$result = ...
.
.       
$this->assertEquals(true, $result);
```

What I want to do is to put the 2nd thing (working around with response) in condition of getting 1st assertion to be true.

Can I do it ? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need any condition - PHPUnit will handle this for you.

It will only continue to assert the remainder of the tests inside your functions if the previous asserts are already true.

i.e.

```
$this->assertResponseOk();

// The previous $this->assertResponseOk() MUST have been true to reach this point
$this->assertEquals(true, $result);
```

Comment: Thats good then, but what If I want to print custom message for success or failure? and also if there any possibility of showing which test is running in case of multiple tests?

Comment: Currently I am doing it like `if($this->assertResponseOk($response)==null) {
echo 'XYZ_TestSuccessful';}` , Its working but definitely not the proper way to do. @The Shift Exchange

Comment: You dont need to say it is successful. PHPUnit will tell you if it is *unsuccessful*. If all your tests pass - PHPUnit tells you.

Comment: I agree with @Fahad, the possibility of adding custom messages like phpUnit does is missing, I think it's an error on Laravel's API.